# Scala: how to transform sequence of strings into a sequence of tuples by splitting strings

Tags: string, scala, sequences

I'm trying to transform a sequence like the one bellow

```
val raw: Seq[String] = Seq("timmy barns", "jimmy smith", "mark middle")
```

into a sequence that would look like this.

```
val parsed: Seq[(String, String)] = Seq(("timmy", "barns"), ("jimmy", "smith"), ("mark", "middle"))
```

The best I can come up with is something like this.

```
val parsed: Seq[(String, String)] = Seq(raw.map(i => i.split(" ")))
```

Obviously this won't work, can anyone give me suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will gracefully, but silently, drop all input that doesn't `split()` into 2 elements.

```
raw.map(_.split("\\s+")).collect{case Array(a,b) => (a,b)}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to combine it with a more general regex matching anyway, this variant might be preferable:

```
val P = "(\\w+) +(\\w+)".r 
val result = for (P(x, y) <- raw) yield (x, y)
```

gives:

```
result: Seq[(String, String)] = List((timmy,barns), (jimmy,smith), (mark,middle))
```

Comment: `\\w+` probably won't work for names like "tim berners-lee".  Maybe `\\S+` instead?

Comment: @LeoC Well, yes... but with "Saunders Mac Lane", even `\\S+` will not work correctly. The advantage of the regex solution (as compared to `split`) is that one has a little bit more flexibility, so that one could admit more symbols in the surname, for example.

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this:-

```
val raw: Seq[String] = Seq("timmy barns", "jimmy smith", "mark middle")

val splitRaw = raw.map { x =>
  (x.split(" ").head, x.split(" ").last)
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

My version )

```
raw.map(_.split(" ") match {
    case Array(a, b) => (a, b)
})
```